# How to identify lat and long for a global matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I am going to use a binary files (climate variable for the globe ) that can be downloaded from here:

```
  ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0301_amsre_ease_grid_tbs/global/
```

This file is a binary (matrix) file with `586 lines and 1383 columns` (global map).
I would like to extract a value that is at   `100 longitude  and 50 latitude`.

I can extract any point using x and y using:

```
    X<-450 ; Y<-145 
    extract<-vector()
file<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=586*1383, signed=T)
file2<-t(t(matrix(data=file,ncol=1383,nrow=586)))
extract[file2]<-file2[X,Y]
```

More info:

```
These data are provided in EASE-Grid projections global cylindricalat 25 km resolution, are two-
      byte 
    Spatial Coordinates:
    N: 90°     S: -90°     E: 180°     W: -180°
```

But my question is how to know to its lat and long? Any idea pleas

Comment: provide example data so we know what you have e.g `dput(head(file*,10))` , do you mean which is how do I know which is lat and which is long?, do you have any other information?!  if not then distinguishing between cases where *-90<lat<90* and *-90<long<90* will be a bit challenging...

Comment: It seems your go at pasting the link to the data failed as it's giving the local address.

Comment: Sorry I added the right path! and I added other information

Comment: It's not clear to me that you have yet followed the instructions in the README.TXT file in the directory immediately above that one you cited: `ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0301_amsre_ease_grid_tbs/readme.txt`. In particular they cite (and you didn't) the link to the "complete documentation" (.i.e. the FM): `http://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0301.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the raster package and convert your data to raster objects. Like:

```
> file<- readBin("ID2r1-AMSRE-ML2010001A.v03.06H", integer(), size=2,  n=586*1383, signed=T)
> m = matrix(data=file,ncol=1383,nrow=586,byrow=TRUE)
> r = raster(m, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
> plot(r)
```

Now you have a properly spatially referenced object, but without a full specification of the cylindrical projection used you can't get back to lat-long coordinates.

Longitude is easy, but latitude not so - my use of -90 and +90 probably makes it right at the poles and the equator but not elsewhere. If its a right cylindrical projection then sines and cosines will work it out, but if you have a projection specification in something like PROJ.4 format then there's better ways of doing it.

There some more info here http://nsidc.org/data/ease/tools.html including a link to some grids that have the lat-long of grid cells for that grid system:

ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/

so for example you can create a raster of latitude for the cells in your data grid:

```
> lat <- readBin("MLLATLSB",integer(), size=4,  n=586*1383, endian="little")/100000
> latm = matrix(data=lat,ncol=1383,nrow=586,byrow=TRUE)
> latr = raster(latm, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
> plot(latr)
```

and then `latr[450,123]` is the latitude of cell [450,123] in your data. Repeat with `MLLONLSB` for longitude.

Comment: I don't see how you can say that `r` is properly spatially referenced - latitude is not regular in this coordinate system and the raster convention here is just false. I think it's misleading to built an object like that. R needs a "rectilinear" grid object probably, but we can just use the native projection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about it.

```
f <- "ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0301_amsre_ease_grid_tbs/global/2002/ID2r1-AMSRE-ML2002170A.v03.06H.gz"
download.file(f, basename(f), mode = "wb")

con <- gzfile(basename(f), open = "rb")
mdat <- readBin(con, integer(), size=2,  n=586*1383, signed=TRUE)
close(con)

mdat <- matrix(data = mdat,ncol=1383,nrow=586,byrow=TRUE)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
## build a dummy longlat raster and project its extent
## this proj string may not be enough, should be documented though
prj <- "+proj=cea +ellps=WGS84"
ex <- extent(projectExtent(raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -90, ymx = 90, crs = "+proj=longlat"), prj))

r <- setValues(raster(ex, nrows = 586, ncols = 1383, crs = prj), mdat)
```

Now we can plot this raster in its native form, and transform other data to it:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(r)
plot(spTransform(wrld_simpl, CRS(projection(r))), add = TRUE)
```

[image]