# How to create a grid from 1D array using R?

Tags: arrays, r, matlab

I have a file which contains a 209091 element 1D binary array representing the global land area
which can be downloaded from here:
ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_flags_2002/
I want to create a full from the 1D data arrays using provided ancillary row and column files .globland_r and globland_c    which can be downloaded from here:
ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_ancil/

There is a code written in Matlab for this purpose and I want to translate this Matlab code to R but I do not know Matlab

```
     function [gridout, EASE_r, EASE_s] = mkgrid_global(x)
     %MKGRID_GLOBAL(x)  Creates a matrix for mapping   
     % gridout = mkgrid_global(x) uses the 2090887 element array (x) and returns

     %Load ancillary EASE grid row and column data, where <MyDir> is the path to 
     %wherever the globland_r and globland_c files are located on your machine.
    fid = fopen('C:\MyDir\globland_r','r');
    EASE_r = fread(fid, 209091, 'int16');
    fclose(fid);


     fid = fopen('C:\MyDir\globland_c','r');
     EASE_s = fread(fid, 209091, 'int16');
     fclose(fid);



    gridout = NaN.*zeros(586,1383);

    %Loop through the elment array
    for i=1:1:209091     

    %Distribute each element to the appropriate location in the output
    %matrix (but MATLAB is
    %(1,1)

    end
```

## EDit following the solution of @mdsumner:

The files `MLLATLSB` and `MLLONLSB (4-byte integers)` contain latitude and longitude `(multiply by 1e-5)` for geo-locating the full global `EASE grid matrix (586×1383)` 
`MLLATLSB` and `MLLONLSB` can be downloaded from here:
ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_ancil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## the sparse dims, literally the xcol * yrow indexes
dims <- c(1383, 586)

cfile <- "ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_ancil/globland_c"
rfile <- "ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_ancil/globland_r"

## be nice, don't abuse this
col <- readBin(cfile, "integer", n = prod(dims), size = 2, signed = FALSE)
row <- readBin(rfile, "integer", n = prod(dims), size = 2, signed = FALSE)

## example data file
fdat <- "ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/nsidc0451_AMSRE_Land_Parms_v01/AMSRE_flags_2002/flags_2002170A.bin"

dat <- readBin(fdat, "integer", n = prod(dims), size = 1, signed = FALSE)


## now get serious
m <- matrix(as.integer(NA), dims[2L], dims[1L])
m[cbind(row + 1L, col + 1L)] <- dat


image(t(m)[,dims[2]:1], col = rainbow(length(unique(m)), alpha = 0.5))
```

Maybe we can reconstruct this map projection too.

```
flon <- "MLLONLSB"
flat <- "MLLATLSB"
## the key is that these are integers, floats scaled by 1e5 
lon <- readBin(flon, "integer", n = prod(dims), size = 4) * 1e-5
lat <- readBin(flat, "integer", n = prod(dims), size = 4) * 1e-5

## this is all we really need from now on
range(lon)
range(lat)

library(raster)
library(rgdal)  ## need for coordinate transformation
ex <- extent(projectExtent(raster(extent(range(lon), range(lat)), crs = "+proj=longlat"), "+proj=cea"))

grd <- raster(ncols = dims[1L], nrows = dims[2L], xmn = xmin(ex), xmx = xmax(ex), ymn = ymin(ex), ymx = ymax(ex), crs = "+proj=cea")
```

There is probably an "out by half pixel" error in there, left as an exercise.

Test

```
plot(setValues(grd, m), col = rainbow(max(m, na.rm = TRUE), alpha = 0.5))
```

Hohum

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(spTransform(wrld_simpl, CRS(projection(grd))), add = TRUE)
```

We can now save the valid cellnumbers to match our "grd" template, then read any particular dat-file and just populate the template with those values based on cellnumbers. Also, it seems someone trod nearly this path earlier but not much was gained:

[How to identify lat and long for a global matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244810/how-to-identify-lat-and-long-for-a-global-matrix?rq=1)